# Почему Idea предлагает 2 варианта одного и того же jdk при создании проекта?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, openjdk

Возможно, нубский пустяковый вопрос, но мне для понимания. Ибо про нейминг версий jdk я хоть и много вроде прочитал, но так до конца, как мне кажется, не разобрался.
Ubuntu 20.04. Установил java 16 jdk через sudo apt install openjdk-16-jdk. Запускаю идею и вижу, что она мне предлагает на выбор 2 варината одного и того же jdk (см скриншот) в папке инсталяции java также есть упоминание как 16 так и 1.16 версии. В чем причина такого странного поведения идеи? Это действительно одно и то же или есть разница что выбрать при старте проекта? И почему в папке инсталяции нельзя было все называть либо через 16 либо через 1.16?[image: идея][image: на диске]

Comment: 2 каталога - 2 версии. Всё логично. Один из каталогов - это ссылка на другой, если я не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью команды `file` вы можете убедиться, что `java-1.16.0-openjdk-amd64` это [символическая ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) на директорию `java-16-openjdk-amd64`:

```sh
$ file /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.16.0-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.16.0-openjdk-amd64: symbolic link to java-16-openjdk-amd64
```

Начиная с Java 1.5 версионирование [изменилось](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java#J2SE_5.0), первое число в номере версии отбросили, и стало просто Java 5.

Вы можете попробовать удалить эту символическую ссылку, но, возможно, какие-то другие программы могут использовать прежний стиль версионирования и не найдут установленную OpenJDK на вашем компьютере.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ! Теперь вроде все встало на свои места.